# What is the difference between adding cipher.update() and cipher.final() and concating them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes

What is the difference between

```
   let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
   const res = Buffer.concat([encrypter.update(data), encrypter.final()]);
```

and

```
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
const res = cipher.update(data)+ cipher .final();
```

Comment: Your code does not look right to me.  Encrypter is not defined in the first snippet.  I think you mean to have cipher there instead of encrypter.

Comment: `concat()` concatenates the two buffers `cipher.update(data)` and `cipher.final()` into one buffer. `+` causes the two buffers to first be implicitly converted to strings using UTF-8 (since no output encoding was specified) and then concatenated. The UTF8 decoding _corrupts_ the ciphertext, i.e. this way does generally not work. See also the docs for [`update()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_update_data_inputencoding_outputencoding) and [`final()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_final_outputencoding).